# Detect changes in dataset

Tags: dataset, group-differences

I need at least a couple of keywords to get me started and read for my self.

Suppose I have a number $M$ of populations. From each population, I draw $R$ replicas of a parameter vector $\vec x$ of $N$ dimensions. In total, I have $R\times M$ samples of $N$-dimensions each.

I want to see what components of $\vec{x}$ are different across across the populations. I would like a way to detect the most significant variations. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using R?

Comment: @Brunaw Python :)

Comment: I can't help you them, I use only R ): but I can tell tou that this question might be better answered in Stack Overflow (btw, the answer is yes, it's possible)

Comment: @Brunaw Perhaps if you tell me the name of the method, I can look it up. How would you do it in R?